# Git use repo as dependency in another repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out an alternative to git submodules for this situation.

I’m creating Car apps with Angular.

I have a master git repo with all the code for a Car that will be reused for all projects. Then I have other repos for different cars with customizations, like a blue car with leather interior, a red car with 20 inch rims, etc. In the customization repos, I just have the stuff that's different, like the paint and interior colors.

I want to include the main repo for the Car in all of the other repos, so I can run a build for a Blue car that has the main Car code plus the changes.

What's the best way to set this up in git?

Comment: If you do not want to use `git submodules` you could  use repo as android do and have manifests for with shared and customized code

Comment: Try not to use git as a means of dependency management. Use something else. I use npm to managed JavaScript dependencies.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think this is the answer, I was going about this the wrong way. Thanks!